# Qt Windows Deployment Process

Tags: windows, qt, deployment

I am in the process of learning how to create applications using Qt. I created a small app that is running fine on any machine that has Qt installed. I want to deploy using dynamically linked Qt libraries to Windows. I followed the instructions found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) and with some help of other Stackoverflow articles I was able to get the application running without error, but now nothing shows up. There should be a small UI with buttons and such, but it isn't being displayed despite the fact that Windows Task manager reveals that the application is running.

My first thought was that I was missing some dll files, but even if I copy every dll found in C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin, the entire C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\plugins directory, msvcp120.dll, msvcr120.dll and the plaforms\qwindows.dll to the application directory I still cannot get it to display the UI.

The same application will run on any Win x64 machine with Qt installed. I just don't find asking users to download a 700mb set of tools to run a 9kb application a very robust solution.

What step am I missing for Qt deployment to Windows?

For specifics I have made this an [open source project.](https://github.com/CptMonkeyFist/ArkCharacterSelector) You can see the release version of the application built in the bin/Win_x64 directory with all .dll files that I believe are necessary to run the application. If you copy that folder onto a Win x64 machine that doesn't have Qt installed then you should be able to reproduce my error.

Edit1:
I was asked to provide the list of files in my build/Release directory:

```
ArkCharacterSelector.exe
ArkCharacterSelector.res
CharacterManager.obj
Logger.obj
main.obj
moc_CharacterManager.cpp
moc_CharacterManager.obj
qrc_qml.cpp
qrc_qml.obj
```

Comment: The DLLs for the main app must be present for it to run.  You get an OS level error popup when a DLL is missing. See the free tool http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to check for missing DLLs in this area.

Comment: Now the the plugins directory DLLs are needed if you use certain features, like certain file formats.  But I suspect this is not the problem as I would expect your application should appear to start and something appear on screen (as you did not say you are getting an OS level error dialog).

Comment: The next concern is you have built it for 64bit, are you trying to deploy it on 32bit windows ?  Most people create/build for 32bit windows if they want maximum consumption, since it will still work on 64bit windows.

Comment: To help explain where you are at, make a ZIP file of your deployment directory (the one with the EXE and all subfolders and files).  Then get a text listing of the contents, `unzip -lv myapp.zip` and put in your question.

Comment: The `msvc*.dll` should not really be copied into the application directory (doing this might be said to create a security concern), every target system is best to install the official redistributable from Microsoft's website such as https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784 this way the DLL gets Windows Update fixes and your application uses the best available version on the system.

Comment: I tried using dependency walker but errors occurred while processing my executable. It was unable to find some dll's on my system: "IESHIMS.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL, etc" This application runs on the machine I was using just fine (as it has Qt installed). I don't know how to get it to finish its analysis. Of the files it was able to scan, the root level libraries it required were "QT5CORE.DLL, QT5GUI.DLL, QT5QML.DLL, MSVCP120.DLL, MSVCR120.DLL, KERNEL32.DLL, and SHELL32.DLL" Aside from the last two, which should be part of windows, all are included in my bin directory.

Comment: I have no intention of including the msvc*.dll files when I am finished. I only included those so people helping me wouldn't need to install the redistributables.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no errors are occuring in the Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Start with this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the files that are missing from [master/bin/Win_x64](https://github.com/CptMonkeyFist/ArkCharacterSelector/tree/dc2cd47d2b422142787d1609f350f789dcfc3d38/bin/Win_x64):

```
bin/Win_x64
├── QtQuick (both dirs are from qt_base_dir/qml/QtQuick)
│   ├── Controls
│   └── Window.2   
├── QtQuick.2 (both files are from qt_base_dir/qml/QtQuick.2)
│   ├── qmldir
│   └── qtquick2plugin.dll
│
│   (Those are only needed for QtWebKit builds)
├── icudt53.dll
├── icuin53.dll
└── icuuc53.dll
```

And these files can be removed:

```
bin/Win_x64
└── platform
    ├── qwindowsd.dll (debug dll)
    └── qwindowsd.pdb (only needed for debugging the debug dll)
```

Happy deployment!

Comment: Thanks a ton. How did you know to do this? After reading your solution I found instructions that would have eventually led to this solution at https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows, but it appears to be a grueling process of "delete file x and see if it still works".  Is this what you did?

Comment: After many Qt deployments on Windows, I've become familiar with the  binary dependencies of the major Qt modules.
That wiki page's approach is foolproof, but a bit tedious. Check out `windeployqt.exe` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). It automatically finds and copies all necessary binaries.